# Can I get around the no-update restriction in HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Thanks for the answers. I'm still not quite getting the answer I want. It's a particular question involving HDFS and the concat api.

Here it is. When concat talks about files, does it mean only "files created and managed by HDFS?" Or will it work on files that are not known to HDFS but just happen to live on the datanodes?

The idea is to

- Create a file and save it through HDFS. It's broken up into blocks and saved to the datanodes.
- Go directly to the datanodes and make local copies of the blocks using normal shell commands.
- Alter those copies. I now have a set of blocks that Hadoop doesn't know about. The checksums are definitely bad.
- Use concat to stitch the copies together and "register" them with HDFS.

At the end of all that, I have two files as far as HDFS is concerned. The original and an updated copy. Essentially, I put the data blocks on the datanodes without going through Hadoop. The concat code put all those new blocks into a new HDFS file without having to pass the data through Hadoop.

I don't think this will work, but I need to be sure it won't. It was suggested to me as a possible solution to the update problem. I need to convince them this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The base philosophy of HDFS is:

> write-once, read-many

then, it is not possible to update files with the base implementation of HDFS. You only can append at the end of a current file if you are using a Hadoop branch that allow it. (The original version doesn't allow it)

An alternative could be use a non-standard HDFS like Map-R file system: https://www.mapr.com/blog/get-real-hadoop-read-write-file-system#.VfHYK2wViko

Answer (score 0):

Go for HBase which is built on top of Hadoop to support CRUD operations in big data hadoop world.
If you are not supposed to use No SQL database then there is no chance for updating HDFS files. Only option is to rewrite.